# How to define a method for a model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I define a method the attribute of a model.

I have a Picture model that has a title.

```
Picture.title = "Some title #with a few #hashtags"
```

I want to make those hashtags links to the tag#show

```
Picture.title.with_links = "Some title <%= link_to "#with", tag_path(tag) %> a few <%= link_to "#hashtags", tag_path(tag) %>"
```

Whats the best way to do this. Where do I define the method(with_links)? in Picture.rb? or Pictures_helper.rb?

Answer (score 0):

In short, Rails model does not have access to routes. In very rare cases it is possible to use routes from within model, however in this case it is not the right place to do so.

The right place for `with_links` is `PicturesHelper`, so that it would be accessible in view via `with_links(picture)`. The declaration would be:

```
def with_links(picture)
  out= "Some title "
  out += picture.tags.collect do |tag|
    link_to(tag.name, tag_path(tag))
  end.join(", ")
  raw out
end
```